# Flux of a vector field through a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

Calculate the flux of $\displaystyle F(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},z)$ through the surface $\displaystyle z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \ \ \ 1\leq z \leq 2$.

The normal has a positive z-component.

**I do not know how to close the surface really.

Comment: You should show your effort. Do you know how to find the normal vector to the surface?

Comment: $n=(-f_x, -f_y, 1)$

Comment: Or I can parametrize the surface and then calculate the cross product of its partial derivatives.

Comment: Yes please convert it into cylindrical coordinates and that is easier to work with.

Comment: If you get stuck, please edit to post your progress